# writing trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am a newbie in MySql and just started learning (as I need to connect it with R for what I am doing).

I am trying to create a database and there are some restrictions that I want to force to my database. For example, I want to make sure that a product is assigned to at least one category. Assuming my category table is:

`CREATE TABLE cat (catid int not null catname varchar(35))`

`CREATE TABLE product (prodid int not null prodname varchar(50))`

Now I want to make sure that each prodid is assigned to at least one category.
I found that this is done in 'sql' using assertion with something like this:

`CREATE ASSERTION AtLeastOneCat 
CHECK NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM product 
where not exists( select * from cat where catid.cat = prodid.product) )`

But then I found out that this doesn't work in mysql, and I have to use trigger instead. But I couldn't figure out how to write an equivalent to the above code in 'mysql'! 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a trigger for this. Use a Foreign Key constraint instead. [Reference here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: @HoboSapiens I read the article. So, do you mean to change the product table to: `CREATE TABLE product (prodid int not null, prodname varchar(50),  catid int, foreign key (catid) references cat(catid) on update restrict )`?

Comment: Jumping in to answer your last comment - That looks correct but will limit you to one category per product. If a product may be in several categories, you will need a table in between them: `CREATE TABLE product_categories (prodid int not null, catid int not null)` . Both columns are in the PK. You can add FK for both columns.

Comment: @Turophile thanks a lot for your comment. Appreciate it.